# Отправка post запроса с android

Tags: android, post

Добрый день. Встала задача написать приложение работающее с API сайта, но не получается правильно сформировать запрос. API выглядит примерно таким образом:

Получить данные пользователя

```
{
    "type":"get_user_data",              обязательное
    "user_data":{
        "access_key":"XXXX",        обязательное
    }
}
```

Для регистрации:
Для получения кода на телефон

```
{
    "type":"reg",              обязательное
    "user_data":{
        "phone":"9289997755"    обязательное
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь отправлять запросы с помощью httpPost, задавая параметры через такую конструкцию:

```
              List pairs = new ArrayList();
              pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "reg"));
              pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "999999999"));
```

но сервер выдает ошибку о том, что введены некорректные данные. Вопрос в чем, правильно ли я формирую свой запрос, или нужна другая конструкция?

Answer (score 2):

Это же JSON, ищите POST json Android, там в первых же ссылках все расписано.
К примеру тут [json post](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F6218143%2Fandroid-post-json-using-http&ei=6goCUvH1Cceu4ASB-YG4AQ&usg=AFQjCNFMgUJUhOK_n1GKBU44kKcZaSdDpw&sig2=H-9fZXHocLSDg9efsIhaJA&bvm=bv.50310824,d.bGE&cad=rjt)